# Keep SecureRandom (SHA1PRNG) seed secret - calculate hash before seeding?

Tags: java, random, hash, random-seed

I'm using SecureRandom with SHA1PRNG to generate a random sequence. I won't let SecureRandom seed itself, I'm using my own values to seed it. (Please don't tell me that this is unsafe, I have my reasons for doing this).

However, I don't want anyone to know what seed I used. The seed must remain secret and it shouldn't be possible to recalculate the seed from the random sequence.

Does it make sense to calculate the SHA-512 from my value and seed SecureRandom with it? Or will SecureRandom create a SHA1 hash from the seed itself?

Long story short: Should I seed SecureRandom with "value".getBytes() or with the SHA-512 hash of "value", if I want to keep "value" secret?

Where can I find information how the SHA1PRNG algorithm works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security-wise, there isn't any real difference between using a static value, or using the hash of a static value.  Since `sha1(x)` is always the same value, you've really just traded one static value for a different static value.

Either way, if someone goes to the trouble of disassembing your program they're going to find out what seed you're using.

Comment: In fact, I initialize SecureRandom with a static value concatenated with a random value. And I won't release my program, but  random sequences which it generated. Do I understand correctly that it won't be possible to recalculate the seed even if I don't SHA-512 it before seeding?

Comment: Correct.  But the security of this system is directly related to how hard it would be to guess the random bits that went into your seed.  There have been tons of security breaks around weaknesses in PRNG and seeds, so you should (1) assume that an attacker has access to your source code (2) collect enough unguessable bits and (3) seed your PRNG with sha_512(concat(static,random)).

Comment: Lately, people have started to wonder about even using `/dev/random` as a data source.  It is supposed to be a relatively secure way to get random bits, but lately we've been hearing that on some OSes the NSA may have compromised it.